# Jersey 2 multi-part

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jetty, jersey-2.0

We are having a RESTful webservice that has a resource that accepts multi-part. We are having Jersey2 with Spring 4. I am getting the following exception

```
<code>
org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public javax.ws.rs.core.Response xxx.AssetUploadResource.uploadAssetByStream(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition,java.lang.String) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class xxx.AssetUploadResource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@1d63c523]}, definitionMethod=public javax.ws.rs.core.Response xxx.AssetUploadResource.uploadAssetByStream(java.io.InputStream,org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition,java.lang.String), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=Asset, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition, source=asset, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=Asset Metadata as a json string, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class javax.ws.rs.core.Response}, nameBindings=[]}']
</code>
```

Jersey version is 2.24. Also, the multi-part dependency alongwith init-param in web.xml is added

```
<code>
@Api
@Path("/asset")
@Component
public class AssetUploadResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response uploadAssetByStream(
            @FormDataParam("asset") InputStream asset,
            @FormDataParam("asset") FormDataContentDisposition assetDetails,
            @FormDataParam("metadata") String metadata) {
</code>
```

web.xml

```
<code>

 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jersey-serlvet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>xxx</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
</code>
```

Can you please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: I would like to know too, any solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Spring with Jersey and it seems the `spring-boot-starter-jersey` dependency does not include the necessary dependency for multi-part  form data media type, which is a problem.

Add the dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>2.26</version>
    </dependency>
```

After that you also need to register it. Here is how I did it:

```
@Configuration
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {


    JerseyConfig() {
        // where I keep all my things
        packages(
                "com.mycompany.api"                
        );

        // this is what you are looking for
        register(org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.MultiPartFeature.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: was missing the register if MultiPartFeature. Thanks